I dont know how to import a Cog funtion into my main.py for my discord bot
I'm trying to make a Discord bot that will enable me to run a command from another file using cog, yet it seems to have problems when i try to add my Cog to my main.py file.
Here is the code I have for my main.py:
import discord
import os
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())

async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            cog_name = filename[:-3]  # Remove the '.py' extension
            cog_path = f'cogs.{cog_name}'  # Construct the full path to the cog
            try:
                bot.load_extension(cog_path)
                print(f"Loaded extension: {cog_name}")
            except commands.ExtensionAlreadyLoaded:
                print(f"Extension {cog_name} is already loaded.")
            except commands.ExtensionNotFound:
                print(f"Extension {cog_name} not found.")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.dnd, activity=discord.Game('Playing Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3'))
    print("--------------------------------------------")
    print("Bot is ready")
    print("--------------------------------------------")

@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"Hello there, {ctx.author.mention}!")



my_files = ["ban"]

for file in my_files:
    bot.load_extension(f"cogs.ban")

with open("token.txt") as file:
    token = file.read()
    
bot.run(token)

and here is the code for my command i want it to be able to run (its a ban command):
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Ban(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
    async def ban(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
        await member.ban(reason=reason)
        await ctx.send(f"{member} has been banned!")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Ban(bot))

Each time i run it it always give me following error message:
2024-05-08 10:53:31 ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command ban
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/DEATH-TO-THE-MPLA/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 235, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/DEATH-TO-THE-MPLA/main.py", line 35, in ban
    await ctx.invoke(bot.get_command('ban'), ctx, member, reason=reason)  # Invoke the ban command defined in the Ban cog
  File "/home/runner/DEATH-TO-THE-MPLA/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/context.py", line 336, in invoke
    return await command(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/DEATH-TO-THE-MPLA/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 590, in __call__
    return await self.callback(context, *args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
TypeError: ban() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/DEATH-TO-THE-MPLA/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/DEATH-TO-THE-MPLA/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1029, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "/home/runner/DEATH-TO-THE-MPLA/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 244, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: ban() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given

If anyone could help me out id appreciate it
I've tried using a different post on here: How can I import a cog into my main.py file? to resolve this matter but when i used it, all it did was cause following error:
/home/runner/DEATH-TO-THE-MPLA/main.py:38: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited
  bot.load_extension(f"cogs.ban")
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
2024-05-08 11:00:53 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
2024-05-08 11:00:54 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: 46f7aa5cd5816a4b67bec47342e1e375).
--------------------------------------------
Bot is ready
--------------------------------------------

The bot itself ran, but the command didn't work.

you have to await the bot.load_extension for your second error

The logs mention
  File "/home/runner/DEATH-TO-THE-MPLA/main.py", line 35, in ban
    await ctx.invoke(bot.get_command('ban'), ctx, member, reason=reason)  # Invoke the ban command defined in the Ban cog

In ctx.invoke(bot.get_command('ban'), ctx, member, reason=reason) you are effectively providing ctx twice. Try ctx.invoke(bot.get_command('ban'), member, reason=reason)
This part of the code is not not included in the code you shared with us. If you still encounter issues, please share all the relevant code.

I have made a Music Bot in the past which also uses cogs, and I imported the cogs via asyncio like this:
import asyncio

from NAME_OF_YOUR_COG_FILE import NAME_OF_YOUR_CLASS_INSIDE_THE_COG

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(bot.add_cog(NAME_OF_YOUR_COG_FILE(bot)))

I hope I could help! If it doesn't don't hesitate to contact me!

Although this technically works, you don't need it to be asynchronous because the cog is added before the bot is connected (or on connect). There's a reason the library keeps it synchronous.
